# Error on building and installing memcached php extension

Tags: linux, centos, php

I have problems to run make on the latest memcached PHP extension, on CentOS 6.5:

```
pecl download memcached

tar zxvf memcached-2.2.0.tgz

cd memcached-2.2.0/

phpize

./configure --disable-memcached-sasl --with-libmemcached-dir=/usr

make
```

Then i get the following error:
https://gist.github.com/adionditsak/b704ef4328e7f258d7e0

Comment: Did you install `libmemcached-devel`?

Comment: Yes - Package libmemcached-devel-0.31-1.1.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version

Comment: I get the same errors as these guys: https://github.com/php-memcached-dev/php-memcached/issues/69 - tried both from pecl and github

Comment: I can see a lot of people have the same errors... and no solution, really...

Comment: memcached-2.2.0 required libmemcached 1.0 and later. You need to compile libmemcached first since centos default package is too old.